# Create web services on the fly based on WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

Using some Java library I want to provide web services to clients at run time. The web services should be based on WSDL definitions, which are unknown at compile time. The web service implementation itself will be some generic implementation getting the service name and field values and passing it to some external system (e.g. storing key / values into a database) and fetching the result some seconds later. The implementation is something like a proxy translating services / WSDL unknown at compile time at run time with generic code to backend systems.

I've found libraries doing WSDL -> java code or java code -> WSDL, but what library is capable of dynamically registering WSDL at run time?

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the java [Service](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html) class, which can be used to generate dynamic proxies to a web service.

I didn't find any great new examples, but the 1.4 tutorial has a [walk-through](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC5.html) you might use to get started.